# How to Enable ARCore on Others Android Phone

Tags: android, session

How to Enable ARCore on Others Android Phone?  Some errors occurred while using:

```
2020-04-01 19:13:07.053 26010-26024/com.google.ar.core E/native: calibration_jni.cc:210 No device profile available for build fingerprint qti/sdm660_64/sdm660_64:9
2020-04-01 19:13:07.058 26389-26389/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/native: session_create_implementation_shared.cc:1821 Unable to obtain device profile from the content provider: NOT_FOUND: Device is not supported.
2020-04-01 19:13:07.059 26389-26389/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/native: session_create_implementation.cc:248 Failed to create calibration config and device profile.
2020-04-01 19:13:07.059 26389-26389/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar W/native: session_create_implementation.cc:249 createImplementationWithFeaturesAndSettings returning NOT_FOUND: 
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation_shared.cc:1825
     [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_UNAVAILABLE_DEVICE_NOT_COMPATIBLE'].
2020-04-01 19:13:07.059 26389-26459/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar V/third_party/redwood/infrastructure/jni_common/jni_helper.cc: ~JniHelper: about to detach thread (Called from line 336).
2020-04-01 19:13:07.059 26389-26459/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar V/third_party/redwood/infrastructure/jni_common/jni_helper.cc: ~JniHelper: detached thread (Called from line 336).
2020-04-01 19:13:07.059 26389-26389/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/native: error_policy_util.cc:260 
    ################ ARCore Native Error ##################
    BUILD_CHANGELIST:299933734
    BUILD_BASELINE_CHANGELIST:298253616
    ################### Stack Trace Begin ################
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation_shared.cc:1825 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation_shared.cc?g=0&l=1825
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation.cc:320 https://cs.corp.google.com/piper///depot/google3/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/implementation/session_create_implementation.cc?g=0&l=320
    ################### Stack Trace End #################
com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar E/hello_ar_example_c: *** CHECK FAILED at D:\AS_WorkSpace\arcore-android-sdk-master\arcore-android-sdk-master\samples\hello_ar_c\app\src\main\cpp\hello_ar_application.cc:79: ArSession_create(env, context, &ar_session_) == AR_SUCCESS
2020-04-01 19:13:07.060 764-764/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-04-01 19:13:07.064 26389-26389/com.google.ar.core.examples.c.helloar A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 26389 (mples.c.helloar), pid 26389 (mples.c.helloar)
2020-04-01 19:13:07.171 764-764/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 73 lines
```

Comment: Please give your Question some structure by using the Rich Text features and give more detail about the problem you are trying to solve. which os, wich phone, source code snippets if applicable and how did you try to fix the problem.